# Google Sheets Node.JS API v4 thinks I do not pass valueInputOption to the request when it is clearly there

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am currently trying to modify a row of a given spreadsheet using the Google Sheets API v4. Part of the standard for the update request is passing in a "valueInputOption" as part of the request.

Currently, I am working with the Node.JS version of the API. My request so far looks like this:

```
var request = {
    "spreadsheetId": '1O3jnpFXCdjA7NVE13ERTtqcL4pUWqxj-y_0GoYK2b2o',
    "range": 'FighterZ Info!A' + index + ':G',
    "resource": body,
    "valueInputOption": "RAW",
    "auth": authClient
};
```

However, whenever I execute my request, I am met with this error:

```
{ Error: 'valueInputOption' is required but not specified
at new RequestError (/Users/jtelmo/Desktop/NorCal DBFZ Bot/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:34:42)
at Request._callback (/Users/jtelmo/Desktop/NorCal DBFZ Bot/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:96:27)
at Request.self.callback (/Users/jtelmo/Desktop/NorCal DBFZ Bot/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:159:13)
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/jtelmo/Desktop/NorCal DBFZ Bot/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:159:13)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/jtelmo/Desktop/NorCal DBFZ Bot/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:254:19)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:164:20)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1062:12)
```

code: 400,
  errors: 
   [ { message: '\'valueInputOption\' is required but not specified',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'badRequest' } ] }

Am I doing something wrong here? Am I not putting this valueInputOption key where it is supposed to go?

Answer (score 0):

You're using strings as the attribute names in the API request object:

```
var request = {
    "spreadsheetId": '1O3jnpFXCdjA7NVE13ERTtqcL4pUWqxj-y_0GoYK2b2o',
    "range": 'FighterZ Info!A' + index + ':G',
    "resource": body,
    "valueInputOption": "RAW",
    "auth": authClient
};
```

Change it to use plain attribute names, like this:

```
var request = {
    spreadsheetId: '1O3jnpFXCdjA7NVE13ERTtqcL4pUWqxj-y_0GoYK2b2o',
    range: 'FighterZ Info!A' + index + ':G',
    resource: body,
    valueInputOption: "RAW",
    auth: authClient
};
```

Comment: This is the relevant info of the request object after I built and log it out:
`{ valueInputOption: 'RAW',
  spreadsheetId: '1O3jnpFXCdjA7NVE13ERTtqcL4pUWqxj-y_0GoYK2b2o',
  range: 'FighterZ Info!A11:G',
  resource: { values: [ [Array] ] },
`

I am still getting the same exact error after making the improvement you suggested.

Comment: I've got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of V25 (and V26 as well), Ref

https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/964

I.e., change it to version 24.0.0 and it'll work as expected.